# Example of non-commutative ring such that every ideal is two sided

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can you give an example of non-commutative ring $R$ such that every ideal is two sided?

Comment: [The DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=84l&H=84r&L=1) for noncommutative left-and-right duo rings (the type of ring we are talking about) yields only one further hit; however, finite products of such rings are also duo rings, so one can easily produce different ones that aren't simply division rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a noncommutative division ring - for example, take $R = \mathbb{H}$. Since it's a division ring, the only (right/left) ideals are the trivial ideal. Thus every ideal is two sided.

Answer (score 1):

The quaternions. Every ideal is either $(0)$ or the whole ring.

Comment: Damn. Beat me to it. :P